# AlterField migration works for some fields, not others, but all have the same change

Tags: django-migrations

I have a migration that changes a varchar field to a foreign key field. In the database there aren't any values for those varchar fields - all the values are null, so that's not a factor in this problem. Two of the AlterField operations worked without any issues, but the other two failed. When we tried to run the migration, we get a ValueError that the related model cannot be resolved.

Here's what's in models.py - the code is actually on another system and I'm retyping. I also can't put in the real names, due to security issues, so I'm obfuscating the names:

```
class A(DisplayValuePair):
    pass

class B(DisplayValuePair):
    pass

class C(DisplayValuePair):
    pass

class D(DisplayValuePair):
    pass

class PropertiesFile(models.Model):
    # there lots of other foreign key fields that already exist in the model
    # that are defined the same way, but these are new. The fields used to all
    # be models.CharField
    my_a_field = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=_PROTECT)
    my_b_field = models.ForeignKey(B, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=_PROTECT)
    my_c_field = models.ForeignKey(C, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=_PROTECT)
    my_d_field = models.ForeignKey(D, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=_PROTECT)
```

When makemigrations is executed, the migration that is created is

```
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name="propertiesfile",
    name="my_a_field",
    field=models.ForeignKey(blank=true, null=True, 
                            on_delete=django.db.models.delete.PROTECT,
                            to='data_exporter_app.A'),
),
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name="propertiesfile",
    name="my_b_field",
    field=models.ForeignKey(blank=true, null=True, 
                            on_delete=django.db.models.delete.PROTECT,
                            to='data_exporter_app.B'),
),
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name="propertiesfile",
    name="my_c_field",
    field=models.ForeignKey(blank=true, null=True, 
                            on_delete=django.db.models.delete.PROTECT,
                            to='data_exporter_app.C'),
),
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name="propertiesfile",
    name="my_d_field",
    field=models.ForeignKey(blank=true, null=True, 
                            on_delete=django.db.models.delete.PROTECT,
                            to='data_exporter_app.D'),
),
```

When I run the migration on one particular server, it fails on changing my_c_field. The first two, my_a_field and my_b_field, convert to foreign key fields in the table without any issues. But my_c_field and my_d_field fail. Other than the names, they are defined the same way in the models.py file.

I found a fix but I'm stumped why it has to be done this way. I left class A and class B alone, and I moved the definition of C and D within the PropertiesFile class.

```
class PropertiesFile(models.Model):

    class C(DisplayValuePair):
        pass

    class D(DisplayValuePair):
        pass

    # there lots of other foreign key fields that already exist in the model
    # that are defined the same way, but these are new. The fields used to all
    # be models.CharField
    my_a_field = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=_PROTECT)
    my_b_field = models.ForeignKey(B, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=_PROTECT)
    my_c_field = models.ForeignKey(C, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=_PROTECT)
    my_d_field = models.ForeignKey(D, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=_PROTECT)
```

If the definition of class C and class D are within the models.py file, then how is it failing to resolve the use of those classes within PropertiesFile, unless I move them into PropertiesFile?

Answer (score 0):

After trying this on different servers, the problem was isolated to a terminal session timeout. Timeout was leaving the migration in some sort of hung state, so that trying to just do the remaining AlterField operations was failing. I think it was a classic case of the real error being something else, but all the migration could figure out was that it couldn't resolve a class, so it threw that error.